# java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\cfg\users (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web, servlet-3.0

I have created a Dynamic Web Project (to generate and send a report)

Project Hierarchy in Eclipse

```
Project
  src(folder)
         -metier(Package)
                  -Util.java(Class)
         -web
                  -ControlleurServlet.java (Servlet)  
  cfg(folder)
         -USERS(file) 

  WebContent
         - gui.jsp (Html form)
```

When I run Util class (Method : sendMail) as a Java project it's working :

Util Class :

```
public class Util {
    static String cvsSplitBy = ";";
public  static String MAILCONFIGURATION="./cfg/mailConfiguration";
public  static String USERS="./cfg/users";
public  static String SHIFTS="./cfg/shifts";
.
.
.
```

sendMail method retreive some data from files.

but when I run the project on server and  invoke sendMail from the Servlet I got this error :

```
INFO: Server startup in 10135 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\cfg\users (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at metier.Util.getUsers(Util.java:130)
    at web.ControleurServlet.doGet(ControleurServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could you please help?

Regards

Comment: Your using relative paths. Relative paths are resolved from the **current** directory. The current directory is the directory from which the JVM is started. In your case, the directory from which your Tomcat server is started. Use absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

servlet context not pointing the same path where you kept your files,

so you can check the context path and keep your folders at appropriate location.

it should solve your problem